# How to use the expando properties for a User object in webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to use to expando proprties of the User object:

```
    user = self.auth.store.user_model.create_user(username, password_raw=password)
    user.name = username
```

But I receive an error message:

```
    user.name = username
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How should I do this for a User object instead of a tuple?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_user` returns a tuple of `created, user` - the first is a boolean flag which shows whether or not the object was created.

```
created, user = self.auth.store.user_model.create_user(...
```